# In installation of "getSpatialData" package, i'm getting Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: How to deal with this?

Tags: r, package, spatial

I'm installing "getSpatialData" package with following codes:

```
  devtools::install_github("16EAGLE/getSpatialData")
  library(getSpatialData)
```

and when I'm loading library(getSpatialData), I'm getting following in this console:

```
Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:devtools::install_github("16EAGLE/getSpatialData")
Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:library(getSpatialData)
```

Also, no functions of getSpatialData package is made availble after loading libraries.

Please someone help! I'm new in R and making terible blunders.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Maybe see if you need to update `devtools` (or any other package)?

Comment: Unless you have already assigned the website address to a variable, it would appear you do not have a path showing the website address to the github site.